# How to add navigation functions in a crossword grid using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I followed [this](https://codepen.io/adrianroworth/pen/OpeyZq) to create my own crossword:

The html file goes like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>The Weekly Crossword</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./mystyle.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- partial:index.partial.html -->
<input type="checkbox" name="checkvaliditems" id="checkvaliditems" />
<label for="checkvaliditems">Let's check as we go?</label>

<div class="crossword-board-container">

    <div class="crossword-board">
        <!-- ROW 1 -->
        <input id="item1-1" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[dD]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item1-2" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[iI]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item1-3" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[pP]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item1-4" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[pP]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item1-5" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[eE]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item1-6" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[tT]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <!-- ROW 1 -->
        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <input id="item2-1" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[rR]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item2-2"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item2-3"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item2-4"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item2-5"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item2-6"></span>
        <!-- ROW 2 -->
        <!-- ROW 3 -->
        <input id="item3-1" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[aA]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item3-2"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item3-3"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item3-4"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item3-5"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item3-6"></span>
        <!-- ROW 3 -->
        <!-- ROW 4 -->
        <input id="item4-1" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[gG]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item4-2" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[rR]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item4-3" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[aA]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item4-4" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[wW]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <input id="item4-5" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[pP]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item4-6"></span>
        <!-- ROW 4 -->
        <!-- ROW 5 -->
        <input id="item5-1" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[oO]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item5-2"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item5-3"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item5-4"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item5-5"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item5-6"></span>
        <!-- ROW 5 -->
        <!-- ROW 6 -->
        <input id="item6-1" class="crossword-board__item" type="text" minlength="1" maxlength="1" pattern="^[nN]{1}$" required="required" value="" />
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item6-2"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item6-3"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item6-4"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item6-5"></span>
        <span class="crossword-board__item--blank" id="item6-6"></span>
        <!-- ROW 6 -->
        <div class="crossword-board crossword-board--highlight crossword-board--highlight--across">
            <span id="across-1" class="crossword-board__item-highlight crossword-board__item-highlight--across-1"></span>
            <span id="across-2" class="crossword-board__item-highlight crossword-board__item-highlight--across-2"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="crossword-board crossword-board--highlight crossword-board--highlight--down">
            <span id="down-1" class="crossword-board__item-highlight crossword-board__item-highlight--down-1"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="crossword-board crossword-board--labels">
            <span id="label-1" class="crossword-board__item-label crossword-board__item-label--1"><span class="crossword-board__item-label-text">1</span></span>
            <span id="label-2" class="crossword-board__item-label crossword-board__item-label--2"><span class="crossword-board__item-label-text">2</span></span>
        </div>
        <div class="crossword-clues">
            <dl class="crossword-clues__list crossword-clues__list--across">
                <dt class="crossword-clues__list-title">Across</dt>
                <dd class="crossword-clues__list-item crossword-clues__list-item--across-1" data-number="1"> headmaster of Hogwarts (last name) when the Chamber of Secrets was opened for the first time (6)</dd>
                <dd class="crossword-clues__list-item crossword-clues__list-item--across-2" data-number="2"> Hagrid's Half Brother (5)</dd>
            </dl>
            <dl class="crossword-clues__list crossword-clues__list--down">
                <dt class="crossword-clues__list-title">Down</dt>
                <dd class="crossword-clues__list-item crossword-clues__list-item--down-1" data-number="1"> ______ Pox; a potentially fatal contagious disease that occurs in wizards and witches (6)</dd>
            </dl>

            </dl>

        </div>

        <div class="crossword-complete">
        Congratulations,
You are awesome!
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
<!-- partial -->

</body>
</html>
```

The css file goes like this:

```
.crossword-board-container {
  position: relative;
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

.crossword-board {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: repeat(6, 16.666667%)/repeat(6, 16.666667%);
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.crossword-board__item {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  background: transparent;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.crossword-board__item:active, .crossword-board__item:focus {
  background: #FFFF74;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
}

.crossword-board__item--blank {
  background: #000000;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  outline: 1px solid #000000;
}

.crossword-board--labels {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 60;
}

.crossword-board__item-label {
  position: relative;
}

.crossword-board__item-label-text {
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 1;
}

.crossword-board__item-label--1 {
  grid-column: 1/1;
}

.crossword-board__item-label--2 {
  grid-column: 1/1;
  grid-row: 4/4;
}

.crossword-board--highlight {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
}

.crossword-board__item-highlight {
  background: #9AFF67;
  display: grid;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
}

/***********************************************************/
/** ACROSS ANSWERS HIGHLIGHTING START                      */
/***********************************************************/
.crossword-board__item-highlight--across-1 {
  grid-column: 1/7;
}

.crossword-board__item-highlight--across-2 {
  grid-column: 1/6;
  grid-row: 4;
}

#item1-1:valid ~ #item1-2:valid ~ #item1-3:valid ~ #item1-4:valid ~ #item1-5:valid ~ #item1-6:valid
~ .crossword-board--highlight .crossword-board__item-highlight--across-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

#item4-1:valid ~ #item4-2:valid ~ #item4-3:valid ~ #item4-4:valid ~ #item4-5:valid
~ .crossword-board--highlight .crossword-board__item-highlight--across-2 {
  opacity: 1;
}

/***********************************************************/
/** ACROSS ANSWERS HIGHLIGHTING END                        */
/***********************************************************/
/***********************************************************/
/** DOWN ANSWERS HIGHLIGHTING START                        */
/***********************************************************/
.crossword-board__item-highlight--down-1 {
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1/7;
}

#item1-1:valid ~ #item2-1:valid ~ #item3-1:valid ~ #item4-1:valid ~ #item5-1:valid ~ #item6-1:valid
~ .crossword-board--highlight .crossword-board__item-highlight--down-1 {
  opacity: 1;
}

/***********************************************************/
/** DOWN ANSWERS HIGHLIGHTING END                          */
/***********************************************************/
#checkvaliditems:checked ~ .crossword-board-container .crossword-board__item:valid {
  background: #9AFF67;
}

.crossword-clues {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 400px;
  width: 340px;
}

.crossword-clues__list {
  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
  padding: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.crossword-clues__list-title {
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 4px;
}

.crossword-clues__list-item {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 4px;
}
.crossword-clues__list-item:before {
  content: attr(data-number) ". ";
}
#item1-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item1-2:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-2:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-2:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item1-3:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-3:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-3:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item1-4:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-4:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-4:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item1-5:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-5:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-5:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item1-6:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-6:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1,
#item1-6:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item4-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item4-2:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-2:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-2:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item4-3:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-3:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-3:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item4-4:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-4:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-4:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item4-5:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-5:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2,
#item4-5:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item1-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item1-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item1-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item2-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item2-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item2-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item3-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item3-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item3-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item4-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item4-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item4-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item5-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item5-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item5-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item6-1:active ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item6-1:focus ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1,
#item6-1:hover ~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1 {
  background: #FFFF74;
}
#item1-1:valid ~ #item1-2:valid ~ #item1-3:valid ~ #item1-4:valid ~ #item1-5:valid ~ #item1-6:valid
~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-1 {
  background: #9AFF67;
}

#item4-1:valid ~ #item4-2:valid ~ #item4-3:valid ~ #item4-4:valid ~ #item4-5:valid
~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--across-2 {
  background: #9AFF67;
}

#item1-1:valid ~ #item2-1:valid ~ #item3-1:valid ~ #item4-1:valid ~ #item5-1:valid ~ #item6-1:valid
~ .crossword-clues .crossword-clues__list-item--down-1 {
  background: #9AFF67;
}

.crossword-complete {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  top: 110%;
  left: 0%;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 1;
  color: red;
  width: 150%;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

#item1-1:valid ~ #item1-2:valid ~ #item1-3:valid ~ #item1-4:valid ~ #item1-5:valid ~ #item1-6:valid ~
#item2-1:valid ~
#item3-1:valid ~
#item4-1:valid ~ #item4-2:valid ~ #item4-3:valid ~ #item4-4:valid ~ #item4-5:valid ~
#item5-1:valid ~
#item6-1:valid ~ .crossword-complete {
  opacity: 1;
}

#checkvaliditems {
  background: #9AFF67;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  left: 37px;
}

[for="checkvaliditems"] {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 40px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  background: #9AFF67;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

As you notice, there is no mechanism to use arrow keys to navigate within the grid. I also would like to have a way to toggle from across to down clues. I think that will require javascript's keycode functionality, but I have no clue how to build this in. Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to move the input focus with the arrow keys in Jquery 3.5.

```
$(window).on("load.crossword", function(event){
  crossword = {};
  crossword.squares = $("input.crossword-board__item");
  $(document).on("keyup.crossword", function(event){
    var element = $(".crossword-board__item:focus");
    if(element.length > 0){
      var coord = element.attr("id").split("-").map(function(value, index){
        return parseInt(/\d/.exec(value));
      });
      switch(event.which){
        case 37: //left arrow
          element = element.prevAll("input.crossword-board__item").get(0) || element;
          break;
        case 38: //up arrow
          element = element.prevAll("input.crossword-board__item#item"+(coord[0]-1)+"-"+coord[1]).get(0) || element.prevAll("input.crossword-board__item[id^=item"+(coord[0]-1)+"]").last().get(0) || element
          break;
        case 39: //right arrow
          element = element.nextAll("input.crossword-board__item").get(0) || element;
          break;
        case 40: //down arrow
          element = element.nextAll("input.crossword-board__item#item"+(coord[0]+1)+"-"+coord[1]).get(0) || element.nextAll("input.crossword-board__item[id^=item"+(coord[0]+1)+"]").last().get(0) || element
          break;
      }
    }else{
      element = crossword.squares.first().get(0);
    }
    element.select();
  });
});
```

I'm not sure what you mean by "toggle from across to down clues," since it's possible to be in a square that's in both an across and a down clue. I'll update the answer upon clarification.

Comment: so, where do these lines go, do I need to create a separate jquery file? What I meant was that currently a particular square shades the relevant clue (across by default) with yellow on the right. By a toggle switch, I would love to switch to down clue for that square.

Comment: But looks like that toggle is not needed, as its automatically shading both of the clues, so no worries there. Let me know how to integrate this script into the existing html and css files

Comment: What environment are you using? In codepen.io, you would go to pen settings > JS > type `jquery` in the `external scripts` area. The lines from the answer would then go in the JS area. If you're running on your own server, you'd use the instructions here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp and include your script in the html `head` the same way with another `script` tag. There are other ways for ruby on rails, etc. Search google for whatever framework you're using.

Comment: Thanks @Evan Messinger. This did solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have accepted the answer, but if you have any idea on how to get the cursor into the next grid automatically once an input is entered (horizontally if working on across clue and vice versa), let me know.